# how to detect popup call in java?

Tags: java, javascript, servlets, web-applications, popup

i am making the call to my servlet from javascript with window.open

```
  window.open('myServlet','window','window Params')
```

i want to detect in myservlet whether call is coming from popup or not without passing any paramater alongwith servlet. Can we detect it in servlet?

Comment: Javascript running on client side vs Servlets running on server side.

Comment: i agree but i was thinking may be browser send some stuff specific to popup to server side

Comment: @user3222249 You mean request headers right?  There is nothing like related to the place of browser being the request fired. at least AFAIK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can with a query parameter

```
window.open('myServlet?from=popup','window','window Params');
```

Use that from parameter in your servlet to detect.

**Edit:**

Since you Don't want to use a query param, It's not possible on server side to know from where(click) this is getting called .

Answer (score 0):

A query parameter would be best (as described by Suresh Atta). One possible alternative - since you can't use a parameter - might be to have two servlet mappings for your servlet - with one of the mappings for just the popup.

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>foo.bar.MyServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<!-- Popup-specific mapping -->
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>myServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/myServlet-popup</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Your popup could reference the popup-specific mapping:

```
window.open('myServlet-popup','window','window Params');
```

Then inside your servlet you could inspect the `HttpServletRequest` to determine the path that was used - and thus whether the servlet was called via the popup or not.

As already said, the parameter method is better. But this might be a possible alternative.